# How to retrieve work items associated to a build in jenkins with pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, tfs, jenkins-pipeline

When i trigger a build in jenkins pipeline i use build.changeSets variable to retrieve all the changes to send by email like this:

```
  def changeSets = build.changeSets
  if(changeSets != null) {
    def hadChanges = false %>
  <table class="section">
    <tr class="tr-title">
      <td class="td-title" colspan="2">Cambios</td>
    </tr>
    <% changeSets.each() { 
      cs_list -> cs_list.each() { 
        cs -> hadChanges = true %>
    <tr>
        <td class="td-subtitle">Usuario:</td>
        <td class="td-author">
        <%= cs.metaClass.hasProperty('commitId') ? cs.commitId : cs.metaClass.hasProperty('revision') ? cs.revision : cs.metaClass.hasProperty('changeNumber') ? cs.changeNumber : "" %>
        <B><%= cs.author %></B>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

but i dont know ho to retrive the workitems associated to this changes, how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TFS as the **Source Code Manager** and build with Jenkins, as you have already retrieved the changesets, then you can get the workitems with the [TFS changeset REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets#with-work-items):

```
GET http://SERVER:8080/tfs/Collection/_apis/tfvc/changesets/{changesetID}/workItems
```

[image]

---

You can also have a try with the Jenkins REST API to retrieve the build details.   (There is a REST API link in the bottom right of each page, jus try to navigate to a specific build, then check the build info with the REST API).

Also check below article, it may helps (The last part):

[Visual Studio Team Services Integration with Jenkins](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/04/25/vsts-visual-studio-team-services-integration-with-jenkins/)

Comment: The problem is that i want to do this from jenkins pipeline, i dont know if i call tfs api from the jenkins piepeline using groovy script.

Comment: @HectorScesa Seems it's not support, please check this thread : https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/5570