# List TFS Work Items during Jenkins Promote

Tags: jenkins, tfs

I am looking for a way to produce all TFS Work Items from a Jenkins promote job.

We have an on prem deployment of TFS with service hooks in place to build the corresponding applications on check-in.  The changeset Id is included with the notification, but I need the TFS work item for that Changeset.

More importantly - we will have several builds run; each with a singular changeset before we actuall run the promotion job.

What I would like to do is find a way to produce the list of TFS work items between releases.  Looking a plug-in or tool that will help produce this.

Answer (score 0):

Update

You should first get the built changeset info in Jenkins side.

There seems to be a `build.changeSets` variable which  could retrieve all the changeset.

Then you could directly use rest api in TFS to query work items info from changeset ID. Detail steps kindly take a look at here:  [How to retrieve work items associated to a build in jenkins with pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424621/how-to-retrieve-work-items-associated-to-a-build-in-jenkins-with-pipeline)

---

According to your description, seems you just want to get all work items between releases (for example: the current release and a previous release).

Retrieve work items by calling

```
https://{account}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/[teamproject]/_apis/Release/releases/{current release id}/workitems?api-version=4.1-preview.1&baseReleaseId={release id}
```

It just return the id, url of work items, and then you need to get details of work item through [Get a list of work items](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#by-ids) REST API.

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for.  However the release pipeline is in Jenkins, not TFS.  The service hook from TFS initiates a build in Jenkins.  I can see the changeset from TFS that initiated the build.  Not every build is promoted (released).  So really what I need is to first determine the changesets built in Jenkins between releases and then query TFS for all of the work items in those changesets?

Comment: Hi JDbennett, yes, there seems to be a `build.changeSets` variable which  could retrieve all the changeset info (not 100% sure since it's in Jenkins side). Then you could  use rest api in TFS to query work items info from changeset ID. Detail steps kindly take a look at here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424621/how-to-retrieve-work-items-associated-to-a-build-in-jenkins-with-pipeline